# symfony 1.4 Fatal error - Call to a member function getCulture() on null (on boolean)

Tags: php, symfony

Ребята помогите понять в каких случаях возникает следующая ошибка

```
$culture = $this->context->getUser()->getCulture();
//Выдает ошибку Call to a member function getCulture() on null
//Пытаюсь решить следующим образом 
$user = $this->context->getUser();
if($user) $culture = $user->getCulture();
else $culture = 'ru';
//бесполезно :(

$this->inst_details['name'] = $this->instrument->getName();
//Выдает ошибку Call to a member function getName() on boolean in ...
```

Интересно то что это ошибку я вывел из логов.Так то я ее не встречал .Вроде работает.Но есть какаято ситуация Когда эти ошибки возникают.

1) Call to a member function foo() on null | on boolean в каких случаях PHP выдает такие ошибки

2) в каких случаях в symfony 1.4 $this->context->getUser()->getCulture(); может выдасть данную ошибку.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться и решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Call to a member function foo() on null | on boolean в каких
>   случаях PHP выдает такие ошибки

Когда вы пытаетесь вызвать метод какого-то объекта, но вместо самого объекта у вас null или false. Это случается, когда вы не обрабатываете ошибки и не проверяете, что является результатом функции, которая создаёт ваш объект.

Например, вы пытаетесь прочитать первую строку из файла, но не проверяете перед этим что файл существует - система выдаст ошибку, что вы пытаетесь выполнить недопустимую операцию. (Это абстрактный пример для иллюстрации)

_

> 2) в каких случаях в symfony 1.4
>   $this->context->getUser()->getCulture(); может выдасть данную ошибку.

Когда метод *getUser()* возвращает null, вместо объекта пользователя. Когда пользовать неавторизован, например:

> It's important to check if the user is authenticated first. If they're
>   not, $user will either be null or the string anon.. Wait, what? Yes,
>   this is a quirk. If you're not logged in, the user is technically the
>   string anon., though the getUser() controller shortcut converts this
>   to null for convenience.
>
> The point is this: always check to see if the user is logged in before
>   using the User object, and use the isGranted method (or
>   access_control) to do this

http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security.html#always-check-if-the-user-is-logged-in

В Symfony 1.4 метод getUser() как раз может вернуть null, в вашем случае именно это и происходит: https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/blob/75d9b19c845d29f6d1809d5bfc9b31d27cc489b6/lib/util/sfContext.class.php#L431

Comment: ваша ссылка для symfony3.1.когда вместо самого объекта  `null` или `false` выдает ошибку `on a none-object`.
В symfony1.4 `$this->context->getUser()->getCulture();` работает нормально если пользователь не авторизован  http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/13-I18n-and-L10n

Comment: Возможно, но смысл это не меняет - ошибка вызвана тем, что метод `$this->context->getUser()` вернул не объект пользователя, а `null`

Comment: А мне кажется что ему передаётся NULL И ошибка об этом.

Comment: Вам неправильно кажется. Кому "ему" передаётся null?

Comment: В сообщении об ошибке так и написано "Попытка вызвать метод getCulture на null". Я добавил в ответ ссылку на исходный код Symfony 1.4, чтобы вы убедились.

Comment: Алексей Уколов `$this->context->getUser()->getCulture();`. Делаю вывод исходя из следующего  `$user = $this->context->getUser(); if($user) $culture = $user->getCulture();`

Comment: Это тот код, который у вас сейчас есть? Или вы так хотите решить проблему? Если второе, то всё верно, если первое, то я не понимаю, как вообще может возникнуть эта проблема в таком случае.

Comment: У меня второй вариант,Так вот и я в непонятках в каких случаях может это возникнуть

Comment: Может, это старые логи и раньше был другой код, который приведён в вопросе?

Comment: Да нет конечно :)